# dynamic table row select and bind

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dynamic

I have a table (id=tbl). and do some job on each row when loading.

```
var loadCheck = function(){
    $('#sTable tbody tr').each(function () {
        do some job...
     });
  }

$(document).ready(function () {
     loadCheck();
 });
```

It works fine. But there is a button in that page. When click the whole table will be recreate dynamically. This time table rows won't be selected.

The Html code is like below:

```
<div id="sTable" style="padding-top:10px;">
       <table id='tbl' border="1" class="table table-hover">
          <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
          </tr>
         <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
            <td>xxx</td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
```

since the div sTable is static but tbl is dynamic. So I bind the tbody to sTable. but still not work. I was tols use $("sTable").on("load"," tbody tr",function(){}) may be good for dynamic binding. but how to handle the "each" function. Any suggestion?

Comment: What functionality are you doing inside of the $. Each?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your `.each()` in another function like:

```
function iteration() {
    $('#sTable tbody tr').each(function () {
       // do some job...
    });
};
```

then call it on page load to initialize it:

```
iteration();
```

and then also call it inside your button `.click()` function.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, but after recreate the table, the  $('#sTable tbody tr') can't be selected.

Comment: oh ok. would you be able to create a jsfiddle of your issue so that we can see what's going on?